# Super quick AVPlayer init or how to start it in background?

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, background-process, avplayer

Scenario:

App is for streaming music from radio station. I'm using AVPlayer for this. App can play music in background (`Required background modes` in plist), App can receive play/pause action from locked screen (with using `AVAudioSessionDelegate` and `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` method).
And this part is ok.

**Problem**

User starts app. When first screen is loaded user tap on "Play" button. Now, in my code, AVPlayer is initialized and as soon as this task is ready it's starting to play music.
But this task last for something like 3 to 5 second even on quick Wi-Fi.

Of course in that 3-5 seconds user can tap on Home Button, app is going to background and AVPlayer never starts to play audio.

How can I handle this? I tried to run `[avplayer play]` in `dispatch_async` but it didn't help.
I also tried to initialize AVPlayer in AppDelegate, and now audio is loading faster, but still, user can be quicker...
What kind of approach to solve this problem is proper?

**Update - code for initializing player**

in header file (MainViewController):
//MyPlayer is subclass of AVPlayer

`@property (nonatomic, strong) MyPlayer *playerBrain;`

implementation file:

```
//lazy instantiation
- (MyPlayer*)playerBrain
{
    if (_playerBrain == nil) _playerBrain = [[MyPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"correct_URL_To_MP3_File"]];
    return _playerBrain;
}

- (IBAction)onOffSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    if (sender.isOn)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            NSLog(@"inside block!");
            [self.playerBrain playRadio];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        [self.playerBrain pause];
    }
}
```

//inside MyPlayer implementation

```
- (void)playRadio
{
     [self play]; //this is method from parent, AVPlayer
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to initialise the player?

Comment: Could you also add some other info like how large/long the file you're trying to play is, how quickly "inside block!" is logged to the console, etc.?

Comment: "inside block" prints almost instantly (less then 1 second after user tap). File is streaming all the time (unless user tap Stop) so I didn't determine the size of it.
I just downloaded similiar app (https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/polskie-radio/id441743093?mt=8) and they also didn't solve this problem.

Comment: If you try to load the audio file from the URL using Safari on the iOS device, how quickly does it start then?

Comment: few seconds. How it's connected to my problem?
Important! when I typed address in Safari (iOS as you said) and tapped home button before it started to play) after few seconds it actually started to play (eventough safari was in background).
(Or maybe not, it's hard to determine if player was loaded or not before I tapped home buttton...

Comment: It's connected because there is probably nothing you can do in your code to help it play faster.

Comment: Ok, but somehow I can put `[myplayer play]` code in background so it connect to stream and start to play even if app was send to background before it started to play. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, haven't tested, but could you play a 1-second silence stored locally on a loop until the audio has loaded? Then your app should still be running in the background, and you could switch out to the real audio once it has loaded.

Comment: How I can determine moment when real audio was loaded?

Comment: You could observe the `status` property on the player. When it changes to `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`, the audio has been loaded.